# Mac & Python 2.7: IDLE doesn't read newly installed libraries but iPython does

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, ipython, python-idle

I just used

```
sudo easy_install wx
```

and

```
sudo easy_install wxpython
```

to install wx and wxpython. Now when I try to run a script which has import wx or import wxpython in it, I get an error message saying that no such library is installed. This only occurs if I write the script in IDLE and then run it. If I do this in iPython then  the modules are loaded correctly. What can be the cause of such an error? How do I find out how to handle and fix such an error?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that IDLE and IPython are running on the same Python?  If not then it's likely that wxPython was only installed in the Python used by IPython and not in the one used by IDLE.

Comment: I am not sure, how would I check something like that? Also, how would I make sure that all of my modules are being installed into the same directory? Sometimes I use sudo pip install some_module and sometimes I use sudo easy_install some_module.

Comment: Do "import sys; print.sys.prefix" in each environment.  The tools like pip and easy_install work with whatever python is used to execute them, so check where they are located and also which python is on the #! line at the top of the script.